# Is it possible to combine two hook_preprocess functions into one in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, preprocessor, hook

The `template.php` file under `sites/all/themes` folder in Drupal 6 consists of two `hook_preprocess` functions. Is it possible to combine those into a single `hook_preprocess` function? Some suitable examples would be appreciated.